# Django moving model from one app to another - ValueError: The field was declared with a lazy reference but app doesn't provide model

Tags: python-3.x, django, virtualenv, database-migration

I am trying to move a model from one application to another. I created two migrations for this purpose.

Migration 1

State operation - Creates model(Foo) in new app

Migration 2 -

Database operation - Alter all the models which have a foreign relation to Foo to point to new app.

State operation - Deletes model(Foo) in old app

class Foo():

```
id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, unique=True)       
name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
```

Foreign Model - Bar

class Bar():

```
foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Moving model Foo to a new app. `The error is field foo.Bar.foo was declared with a lazy reference to 'org.Foo', but app 'org' doesn't provide model 'Foo'.`

When I ran the migrations on my company database, it worked fine and the model was migrated to new app. But when I am running all the migrations to create my local database, it is throwing this error.
Somehow the foreign models are still pointing to the model in old app, not able to figure out where this is happening? Can someone please help.

Command: `python manage.py migrate`

````
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/ishan/.virtualenvs/campaigns-service/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/ishan/.virtualenvs/campaigns-service/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/ishan/.virtualenvs/campaigns-service/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/ishan/.virtualenvs/campaigns-service/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/ishan/.virtualenvs/campaigns-service/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ishan/.virtualenvs/campaigns-service/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 191, in handle
    pre_migrate_apps = pre_migrate_state.apps
  File "/home/ishan/.virtualenvs/campaigns-service/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/ishan/.virtualenvs/campaigns-service/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 210, in apps
    return StateApps(self.real_apps, self.models)
  File "/home/ishan/.virtualenvs/campaigns-service/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 280, in __init__
    raise ValueError("\n".join(error.msg for error in errors))
ValueError: The field org.AbstractCreative.org was declared with a lazy reference to 'org.organization', but app 'org' doesn't provide model 'organization'.```
````

Comment: Please share your model(s)

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem, can you help me on a question???